# Get elements with class which was added with javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, onclicklistener, getelementsbyclassname

```
var courses = document.getElementsByClassName('course');

for(var i = 0; i < courses.length; i++) {
    courses[i].addEventListener('click', function() {
        if(this.classList.contains('active-course')) {
            this.classList.remove('active-course');
        } else { 
            this.classList.add('active-course');
        }
    });
}
```

The above code, adds an event listener on all the elements that contain the class "course" so that when an element with the class is clicked, the class "course-active" is added to it or removed if it already has it.

What I want is to to also get all the elements with the class that was added "course-active" also on click.

When I added the following code in the click event function ( after the if else ), it logs 0

```
console.log(document.getElementsByClass('course-active').length);
// The problem was the typo after all!
// Read EDIT 2 below for more information
```

The class is added, I checked using chrome devtools.
Why aren't the elements found?

---

#### EDIT : HTML as requested

```
<div class="card h-100 course">
    <div class="card-block">
    <h4 class="card-title">AMAT122</h4>
    <p class="card-text">Calculus and Analytic Geometry II</p>
    </div>
    <ul class="list-group list-group-flush">
        <li class="list-group-item">General Department</li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div class="card h-100 course">
    <div class="card-block">
    <h4 class="card-title">AMAT122</h4>
    <p class="card-text">Calculus and Analytic Geometry II</p>
    </div>
    <ul class="list-group list-group-flush">
        <li class="list-group-item">General Department</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

The elements I mentioned above.

---

#### EDIT 2

The problem was A typo after all!

- I wrote `getElementsByClass()` instead of `getElementsByClassName()`
- and I was looking for a different class `.course-active` instead of
  `active-course`

Ooopsy! I think I need to get myself some coffee, hehe

Comment: Could you please add an html to your question?

Comment: Are you trying to add `course-active` or `active-course`, your code seems to be adding the wrong class name

Comment: You need to show the relevant HTML and CSS so we can replicate your issue and provide an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make sure you reference the correct class names. In some cases, you state `course-active` and in others you state `active-course`. Also, you are using `.getElementsByClass()`, instead of `.getElementsByClassName()`.

But, **[`.getElementsByClassName()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName)** is not right for most use cases because it returns a "live" node list which, while ensuring that you always have references to all the items with a certain class, causes it to perform worse than a static one because it has to re-scan the document upon each access of the variable. In most cases **[`.querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll)** is better.

Also, if you convert the node list into an array, you can use the more simple **[`.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)** method to iterate the elements in the array.

Finally, instead of testing each element for the class and then manually adding or removing it, just use the **[`.classList.toggle()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList)** method.

The resulting solution is more efficient and simpler:

```js
// Get all the elements with the course class into an array
var courses = Array.prototype.slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('.course'));

// Loop through the array with the more modern and simpler Array.forEach()
courses.forEach(function(course){
    course.addEventListener('click', function() {
        // Just toggle the use of the class instead of testing for it
        course.classList.toggle('active-course');
    });
});
```

```css
.course { cursor:pointer; }
.active-course { color:red; }
```

```html
<div class="card h-100 course">
    <div class="card-block">
    <h4 class="card-title">AMAT122</h4>
    <p class="card-text">Calculus and Analytic Geometry II</p>
    </div>
    <ul class="list-group list-group-flush">
        <li class="list-group-item">General Department</li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div class="card h-100 course">
    <div class="card-block">
    <h4 class="card-title">AMAT122</h4>
    <p class="card-text">Calculus and Analytic Geometry II</p>
    </div>
    <ul class="list-group list-group-flush">
        <li class="list-group-item">General Department</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Brilliant answer, although I've accepted @edkeveked's answer, I will mark your answer as an answer because you mentioned about the typo in the selector function, the fact that I was looking for a different class than the one I was adding and for the tips/reminders ( .toggle() on classList ).
I intentionally used a for loop as I was told that it performs better than `forEach()`

Comment: @JohnChar It's true that a counting loop on an array is faster than `.forEach()`, but unless you are iterating tens of thousands of items, you'll never see an appreciable difference. `.forEach()` is much simpler and less error prone.

Answer (score 2):

`document.getElementsByClass` is incorrect.

Try `document.getElementsByClassName`

Also the class name you are looking for in your example is incorrect.  You are trying to get elements with the name `course-active` when the class name you are setting is `active-course`.

Comment: Should be `getElementsByClassName`, not `getElementsByClassname`.

Answer (score 1):

You are using `getElementsByClass` instead of `getElementsByClassName`. Also, the class name `course-active` is not the one you added. Consider the snippet below:

```js
var courses = document.getElementsByClassName('course');

for(var i = 0; i < courses.length; i++) {
    courses[i].addEventListener('click', function() {
        if(this.classList.contains('active-course')) {
            this.classList.remove('active-course');
        } else { 
            this.classList.add('active-course');
        }
        console.log(document.getElementsByClassName('active-course').length);
    });
}
```

```html
<div class="card h-100 course">
    <div class="card-block">
    <h4 class="card-title">AMAT122</h4>
    <p class="card-text">Calculus and Analytic Geometry II</p>
    </div>
    <ul class="list-group list-group-flush">
        <li class="list-group-item">General Department</li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div class="card h-100 course">
    <div class="card-block">
    <h4 class="card-title">AMAT122</h4>
    <p class="card-text">Calculus and Analytic Geometry II</p>
    </div>
    <ul class="list-group list-group-flush">
        <li class="list-group-item">General Department</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: That doesn't show what they are doing wrong. It shows the correction. Please make your answers clear and concise.

Comment: The problem was indeed me using `getElementsByClass()` instead of `getElementsByClassName()`, how foolish! Thank you.

Comment: @JohnChar, it happens even to the best of us :)